# Retrieving dependencies from pom file only

Tags: java, maven

I am doing some static mining and I would like to have a list of the involved libraries.

**Is there a way to programmatically find the dependencies used by a pom.xml file ?**

I can not use the .m2 repo or anything in the like since the code DOES NOT compile.

(In other words, I'd like to recreate the "Efective POM" tab of pom.xml file as shown in Eclipse)

Note that reading the pom file of the current project (test boottstrap) gives a set of dependency when asked for - but not with external pom file.
In code :

```
[...]
Model model = mavenReader.read(new FileReader(pomFile));
model.setPomFile(pomFile);

proj= new MavenProject(model);
proj.setRemoteArtifactRepositories(
Arrays.asList((ArtifactRepository) new MavenArtifactRepository(
        "maven-central",
        "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/", 
        new DefaultRepositoryLayout(), 
        new ArtifactRepositoryPolicy(),
        new ArtifactRepositoryPolicy())));

List<Dependency> dependencies = proj.getDependencies();
for (Dependency dependency : dependencies) {
    System.out.println(dependency);
}
```

With `pomFile = new File("pom.xml")` it yelds:

```
Dependency {groupId=com.github.javaparser, artifactId=javaparser-core, version=3.5.4, type=jar}
Dependency {groupId=com.jcabi, artifactId=jcabi-aether, version=0.7.19, type=jar}
Dependency {groupId=org.apache.maven, artifactId=maven-core, version=3.0.3, type=jar}
Dependency {groupId=org.apache.maven.plugins, artifactId=maven-dependency-plugin, version=3.0.2, type=jar}
Dependency {groupId=org.apache.maven.plugin-tools, artifactId=maven-plugin-annotations, version=3.5, type=jar}
```

Using XX advice, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mvn dependency:tree");`

the output is (between others):

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ca.umontreal.iro.logiannot ---
[INFO] ca.umontreal.iro.logiannot:ca.umontreal.iro.logiannot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.github.javaparser:javaparser-core:jar:3.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.jcabi:jcabi-aether:jar:0.7.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcabi:jcabi-aspects:jar:0.7.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcabi:jcabi-log:jar:0.7.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kuali.maven.wagons:maven-s3-wagon:jar:1.1.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kuali.common:kuali-s3:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kuali.common:kuali-threads:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-connector-file:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-connector-asynchttpclient:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.ning:async-http-client:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-connector-wagon:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.struts:struts-core:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.struts:struts-taglib:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.iq80.snappy:snappy:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-analyzer:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-transfer:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.5:provided
```

Which is *quite EXACTLY what I want*. But the point is that I don't want to know what is my project's dependency tree like. I want to investigate other projects.

Now, with `pomFile = new File("[externalPath].pom.xml")` it does not find any dependency. (The file exists and contains proper pom isntructions).

Comment: Are you looking for something like Maven Artifact Resolver? https://maven.apache.org/resolver/index.html

Comment: I am looking for the transitive dependencies. Using a `MavenProject` I get the list of direct dependencies but I would like to know which dependencies use these dependencies, etc.
The resolver seems to ask for a Repository.. I'm gona have a deeper look though, thanks.

Comment: Try `MavenProject.getArtifacts()` or the `MavenProject.get<scope>Artifacts()`

Comment: `MavenProject.getArtifacts()` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a separate process that runs [`mvn help:effective-pom`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html). This command returns an xml with an "effective pom". Later you could parse that XML to obtain dependencies.

In case if you're interested in transitive dependencies you could use `mvn dependency:tree` in a similar fashion.

Comment: The "Effective POM" analogy might be wrong... My apologies. Does it contain dependencies of dependencies ?

Comment: Nope. but `mvn dependency:tree` does :)

Comment: Is there a way to have the result programmatically ? 
I may have more than one pom.xml and it might not be surrounded by any mvn files (I don't know if it could influence the execution/result)

Comment: You could start a process from your code and interpret its output. Or you could look into the plugin [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-3.0.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/tree/TreeMojo.java?view=markup#l217)

Comment: I found what I need thanks a lot. Only need a few parameters to tune the executinon on external files.
Thanks !